# How to Fix the url by dash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite this URL:

```
abc.com/terms-andconditions.php
```

into
    abc.com/terms-and-conditions.html
I did it like this

```
RewriteRule ^terms-and-conditions.html/?$ terms-andconditions.php [NC,L]
```

But after rewriting the URL it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn’t work"?

Comment: it gives me this error

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/abc/public_html/uprofile.php on line 15

Comment: it works on this url terms-andconfitions.html

Comment: This error doesn’t seem to have anything to do with your rewrite rule. Please share the relevant PHP code.

Comment: this error depends on my file name when i change the file name from terms-and-conditions.html to terms-andconditions.html it works perfect

Comment: Not sure how the rewrite can interfere with the MySQLi code, unless you're including a `DB` file somewhere? Can you share the PHP code?